# Cannot count successfully executed mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli, insert-into

I want to see if my query was a success (well, I successfully do the insert query though) but got this error on line 25: "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given " I've already checked every line, I even use mysqli_affected_rows and failed. Appreciate any help, here's my code:

```
<?php
   include "connection.php";  
   $fn = $_POST['first_name'];
   $ln = $_POST['last_name'];
   $uname = $_POST['username'];
   $pwd = $_POST['password'];
   $stat = $_POST['status'];  
   if($fn=="" || $ln=="" || $uname=="" || $pwd=="" || $stat==""){
     echo "ALL FIELD MUST BE FILLED!";
   }                                                                        
   else {
     $sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE username='$uname'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     $number = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   if ($number != 0) {
     echo "Username $uname is not available";
   }
   else {
     $options = ['cost' => 12];
     $pwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
     $query = "INSERT INTO user 
              (username,password,first_name,last_name,status) VALUES 
              ('$uname','$pwd','$fn','$ln','$stat')";
     $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     $nmb = mysqli_num_rows($res);

     echo $nmb;                                                             
    }                                                                         
  }                                                                         
?>
```

Comment: which is line 25? as it means the query is not executed properly

Comment: You are using MySQL, I would suggest using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @FluxCoder This would still have the same problem with PDO.

Comment: @Don'tPanic However, using PDO is much safer, I prefer it as I find it easier to use too.

Comment: So, it is failed after all despite the inserted data successfully inserted into the database. Then, what could be the problem? I mean I've checked every codes, or is it just me?

Comment: PDO is not inherently safer. Using prepared statements is safer, but that's possible in mysqli as well, but it isn't being done here, so I wouldn't assume they would do it with PDO either. (I do prefer it too, though. I agree it's easier.)

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows()` cannot perform on INSERT which is why your query failed. You said you tried to use `mysqli_affected_rows()` and it did not work. Your query failed, that's why and you need to find out why exactly, using `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query/queries. @Crevitz

Comment: mysqli_num_rows won't work on the result of the INSERT query, because that type of query doesn't return a countable result set. If you want to just check that the insert was successful, just use `if ($res)`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic *lol*, I wrote that just above yours ;-)

Comment: @Crevitz you wrote *"I even use mysqli_affected_rows and failed"* - how exactly was the syntax that you used? again, use error checking on all the queries and php's error reporting.

Comment: Guys, you are all right!! I erased the mysqli_num_rows line, replaced it with if($res) and it works!! Thank you so much for your support. By the way, I'm going to use PDO later (on later version I guess?) because this is actually a prototype, a small team project. Thanks for all the tips :D

Comment: @Crevitz What I asked in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098791/cannot-count-successfully-executed-mysqli-query?noredirect=1#comment75218352_44098791) was a question; you didn't respond to it. If you method failed then something wasn't properly written.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I wrote it this way mysqli_query($conn, $query);
printf("Affected rows %d\ rows.n", mysqli_affected_rows($conn));

Comment: @Fred -ii- Well, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$nmb = mysqli_num_rows($res);` can't work, because `$res` is the result of an INSERT query. [The documentation for `mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) says:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Therefore, `$res` will always be either `false` or `true`, and you won't be able to use either `mysqli_num_rows()` or `mysqli_affected_rows()` on it. The thing is, counting rows doesn't really make sense here anyway. You're trying to insert one record, so it's either going to be one or zero, so the true or false result should be sufficient for you to detect whether or not the query was successful.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, pretty much. I added some kind of misleading comments initially, though, because I thought they were referring to the SELECT query at first. I thought an answer would be more definitive, and include a better explanation, and I'm going to delete some of my comments.

Answer (score -1):

change this:

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$nmb = mysqli_num_rows($res);

echo $nmb;
```

for this:

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if ($res) { 
   echo "Insert ok";
}
else
{
   echo "Problem to insert";
}
```

Comment: Basically what the OP stated in comments, but `echo "Problem to insert";` won't ever help them find out the real reason as to why the query could fail.